# Paging in Webgrid with AJAX post request

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this code created in my JS:

```
function PartialViewLoad() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ControllerAlpha/MethodBeta",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        data:
            {
                strFY: $("#strFY").val(),
                strMD: $("#strMD").val(),
                strStatus: $("#strTarget").val(),
                strLead: $("#dropLeads").val(),
                strManager: $("#dropManagers").val(),
                strAppName: $("#strAIRAppName").val()
            },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#dataChart").html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

strTarget, dropLeads, dropManagers and strMD are string arrays.

This code fills up a webgrid created with a razor helper. However, it's not calling the method when a lot of options are selected (around 350). This make impossible call the GET method, because of parameters' length (it's works fine with 50 or so).

> There is possible to page the webgrid using Ajax's POST method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below lines in your web.config file to increase data that can be posted

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" />
</appSettings>
```